# co_await-ed awaitable is not destructed on exception when compiling with GCC10

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-coroutine

Let's suppose we have an awaitable, which throws when resumed:

```
struct always_throws : std::suspend_always {
    void await_resume() {
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
    always_throws() { std::cerr << "always_throws()" << std::endl; }
    ~always_throws() { std::cerr << "~always_throws()" << std::endl; }
};
```

now let's await `always_throws` in a coroutine and run it to completion:

```
Resumable f() {
    co_return co_await always_throws();
}

int main() {
    auto task = f();
    while (!task.ch.done()) {
        task.ch.resume();
    }
}
```

With clang++-10 the destructor is called, but it is **not called** with gcc-10. My question is, is the code correct, i.e. undefined-behavior-free? Or is it a bug in gcc`s coroutine implementation?

Complete example (also with implemetation of `Resumable`): [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/P8qbhb) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TTjaY3).

**EDIT** (15Jul): Gor Nishanov pointed me to a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95491) which is very similar hence probably reports the same issue. Therefore the behavior is indeed a bug.

Comment: Please provide an [mre] in your question, and compile with all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with GCC). Read also the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: Please see the bottom of my question, I posted a link to complete minimal reproducible example on godbolt.

Comment: Please read the C++11 standard, or a newer one. If you believe GCC is buggy, make a carefully written [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) mentioning the C++11 standard (or a newer one, perhaps C++17 [n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)...)

Comment: actually C++20 [(N4860)](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) is required, we don't have coroutines in earlier standards ;-)

Comment: Then please make a GCC bug report, but mention there sections of C++20 standard